# Uploading image and saving data into the database in codeigniter one form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

i am using codeigniter mvc framework, i want to make a form that has a upload picture and also save inputted data in input types in one html `<form>` why is this my image cannot be uploaded and it displays error like this when i echo the error:

```
File cannot be uploadedarray(1) { ["error"]=> string(43) "
You did not select a file to upload.

" }
```

Here is my code in view :

```
<form id="frm_product" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="Admin_controls/addProduct">  
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <a class='btn btn-primary' href='javascript:;'>
                        Choose Picture..
                        <input type="file" style='position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";opacity:0;background-color:transparent;color:transparent;' name="file_source" size="40"  onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'>
                    </a>
                    &nbsp;
                    <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat_name">Product Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat_desc">Description: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_desc">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat_desc">Price: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_price">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat_desc">Category: </label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="prod_cat">
                      <?php foreach($data as $each){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $each->Category_id; ?>"><?php echo $each->Category_name; ?></option>';
                      <?php } ?>  
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Here is my javascript to submit the form:

```
function submitProduct() {
    document.getElementById("frm_product").submit();
}
```

In my controller here is my code:

```
public function addProduct(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploaded_images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload("file_source")) {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
            $file_name =   base_url().'assets/uploaded_images/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
            $data = array (
            'Product_name' => $this->input->post('prod_name'),
            'Product_desc' => $this->input->post('prod_desc'),
            'Product_price' => $this->input->post('prod_price'),
            'Category_id' => $this->input->post('prod_cat'),
            'Product_img' => $file_name
            );
            var_dump($data);    

        }
        else {
            echo "File cannot be uploaded";
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); var_dump($error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: how can you submit this form ??

Comment: @knizer opss i forgot the javascript  i'll edit my post

Comment: where you call this function (submitProduct())??

Comment: You can use codeigniter form helper `form_open('Admin_controls/addProduct')` this here is good for files `form_open_multipart('Admin_controls/addProduct')` explained here  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart]

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thaks this is great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form

`<form id="frm_product" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="Admin_controls/addProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: where would i add it ? please help